# Delphi embedded database with network share support

Tags: database, delphi, networking, embedded-database

I do not know if I'm doing the right question, but this is the situation:

I need to develop an application that will connect to a database.
This same application will be used on 2 computers on the same network (I'll call PC1 and PC2).
The database is on PC1.
The PC2 application should access the database that is on PC1, so both can share the same database.

I want to use an embedded database to be not necessary to install anything beyond my own application in computers.

What better way to do it?
What database should I use?

Thank you.

Comment: If you share an embedded database, you can still use a real SQL database (like firebird or SQLITE). Choose that if you need multi-user, not some kind of ancient flat file system.

Comment: As I remember, SQLite locks whole DB file for any transaction. So I know only one options for correct data sharing (using freeware): Embedded FireBird.
Another solution: [Absolute Database](http://www.componentace.com/absolute_database_features.htm), but it is not freeware.